# Laravel uploading image fails in some images but not in others

Tags: php, laravel

Hy, yesterday I finally uploaded my website to a host, and I had followed a video to upload it. So I created a separeted folder outside public_html to save the files that doesnt belong to public folder, and on public_html I dropped the files from public folder! Now when I try to upload a image gives me always the error **"The foto failed to upload."**, but this happens only for some images not all, and I dont know why! I tryed to disable the validation, but gives me the same error, So I dont think this enter on validation anyways.

My controller code from one controller:

```
    public function store(ParceiroPost $request)
{
    $validated_data = $request->validated();

    $newParceiro = new Parceiros();
    $newParceiro->nome = $validated_data['nome'];
    $newParceiro->url_parceiro = $validated_data['link'];


    if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {

        $image = $request->file('foto');
        $input['imagename'] = time().'_'.$newParceiro->nome.'.png';
     
        $destinationPath = public_path('storage/parceiros');
        $img = Image::make($image->path());
        $img->resize(1280, 868)->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);

        $newParceiro->foto_url = $input['imagename'];
        
    }

    $newParceiro->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.parceiros')
        ->with('alert-msg', 'Parceiro " '. $request->nome .' " foi criado com sucesso!')
        ->with('alert-type', 'success');
}
```

Happens here to, and I save it in a different way:

```
    public function store(StaffPost $request)
{

    $validated_data = $request->validated();

    $newUser = new User;
    $newUser->email = $validated_data['email'];
    $newUser->name = $validated_data['nome'];
    $newUser->tipo = $validated_data['tipo'];
    $newUser->password = Hash::make($validated_data['password']);


    if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
        $path = $request->foto->store('fotos_perfil');
        $newUser->foto_url = basename($path);
    }

    $newUser->save();
    
    $newUser = User::where('email', $validated_data['email'])->first();
    //dd($newUser);
    $newUser->markEmailAsVerified();

    return redirect()->route('admin.staff')
        ->with('alert-msg', 'Staff " '. $newUser->name .' " foi criado com sucesso!')
        ->with('alert-type', 'success');
}
```

Validation:

```
    public function rules()
{
    if(request()->isMethod('put')) // could be patch as well
    {
        return [
            'nome' =>                'required',         
            'foto' =>                'image|max:8192',   // Máximum size = 8Mb
            'link' =>                'nullable',   // Máximum size = 8Mb
        ];
    }
    else
    {
        return [
            'nome' =>                'required',         
            'foto' =>                'image|max:8192|required',   // Máximum size = 8Mb
            'link' =>                'nullable',
        ];
    }
}
```

I think this has to be something with php, because if I comment the all code and just let the return, throws me the error anyways.

This just happens for some images, and I dont know why, because when I am on localhost I can upload those images, but when I am on website I cant

**SOLUTION:**

It was my first time, hosting a website so I dont know that in the file php.ini exists some variables that limits the upload size! For that I changed the value of those variables, so that I could upload bigger files.

Comment: you get error to store image at storage folder path? becuase you define $destinationPath = public_path('storage/parceiros'); like this. so please confirm where you wants to store image. public path Or Storage Path?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: please tell me where you wants to store image... storage path or public path? so i can helps to you better

Comment: @HarshPatel No, because I has a hyperlink to the storage path, on the public folder and this happens on the other controller to, and I save in a different way

Comment: ok i got your error, just wait I put answer

Comment: Is it possible that your php.ini or nginx/appache has a too low  upload max size? Normally this is set at 2MB, if you upload a too large picture apache/nginx or php will fail and not your program.

Comment: @HarshPatel ../storage/app/public/parceiros but on public_html I have a link to ../storage/app/public/

Comment: @Aless55 Maybe, I tryed to find php.ini but I cant on my php folder I dont have nothing with that name

Comment: @GonçaloBastos Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: @Aless55 Apache, but I have CPanel

Comment: Are there any errors in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file (or wherever your logs end up in)

Comment: I put answer of your problem, If you get any problem after this then tell me. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is you are not gives full path... try **"storage_path($destinationPath)"**

I share my sample code, If you get any error tell me... I will update my answer

If you use store or storeAs method from below my code you will need to Load Class in controller...

> **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;**

Then I Function your image upload code will be like this

```
if($request->hasFile('profileimg')){
      $old_profile_photo = $user->profile_photo_path;
      Storage::disk('public')->delete($old_profile_photo);
      $file = $request->File('profileimg');
      $original_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();  
      $file_ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();  
      $destinationPath = 'app/public/users';
      $file_name = "user".time().uniqid().".".$file_ext;
      $file->move(storage_path($destinationPath),$file_name); //save at storage path
      $user->profile_photo_path = "users/".$file_name;
      /*$resize_image = Image::make($file->getRealPath()); //for Resize the Image
      $resize_image->resize(150, 150, function($constraint){ //resize with 150 x 150 ratio
      $constraint->aspectRatio();
      })->save(storage_path($destinationPath) . '/' . $file_name); */
      // $path = $request->profile_img->store('uploads'); 
      // $path = $file->storeAs('users', $file_name, 'public');
      // $user->profile_photo_path = $path; //path store in object variable
     $user->save();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but the problem was the php limit like the @Aless55 said.

Comment: brother assume you have another for failed to upload image, but there are also another mistake about path, So I share... because when I was new in laravel then I faced same issue about image upload, In local it works perfectly but in server was not works perfectly because of path problem

Comment: yes, but I didnt need to use anything from you code! But thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @GonçaloBastos what was your exact problem? & Please share solution of your Question . please put it in answer so it will helps to another ones